# Cronjob no Node, existe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, estou criando um sistema de tarefas e notificações, funciona assim: o user cria uma tarefa para o sistema executar quando chegar num determinado momento, automaticamente, são criadas notificações na base de dados, uma antes de executar, para lembrar o user do que ela vai fazer, e outra na hora, para avisar que ela está acontecendo.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe um jeito de executar um script que fique verificando se existem tarefas para serem cumpridas naquele minuto, e caso existam, faça a execução, de preferencia em Node, meu backend é todo em Node.

Comment: sim. eu tenho uma api rest

Comment: React é front-end, qual BackEnd está usando, ele pode ser configurado isso ...?

Comment: caramba, mds kkk errei. eu sou iniciante nisso. é em node

Comment: talvez isso tenha ferrado com as minhas pesquisas

Comment: Cara, teu backend é em node, recomendo usar [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) pra verificar alguma informação de tempos em tempos

Comment: Muito obrigado Virgilio e Denis. Eu tenho outra dúvida, se vocês pudessem me ajudar, eu ficaria grato mais uma vez. Eu tenho la no meu server o PM2 rodando o a API, pra eu colocar este cron job pra executar, eu posso criar ele dentro do próprio projeto? Tipo, criar ele numa pasta worker e executar ele via pm2?

Comment: Você pecisa ver se esse cron job pode mandar uma requisição para a sua web api e com socket.io atualizar o seu front ... essa seria a lógica inicial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRONJOB não pertence a linguagens, pertence ao sistema operacional, criar um JOB de um script bastaria executar no terminal:

```
crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/bin/node /home/usuario/foo-bar.js
```

E poderia usar estes comandos com a API nativa:

- https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Poderia fazer algo como:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('crontab -e && 00 * * * * /usr/bin/node /home/usuario/foo-bar.js', function(error, stdout, stderr){
   console.log(stdout);
});
```

Não testei, mas provavelmente funcionará (o exemplo é pra servidores linux, lembrando de alterar as pastas conforme as localizações)

Pra **facilitar** você pode instalar via NPM o https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

```
 npm i cron.
```

Exemplo de cron básico https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#usage-basic-cron-usage:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```

**Nota:** Apesar do exemplo sugerir setar a timezone, seria melhor trabalhar com UTC e estudar bem sobre timezones, porque muita gente usa isto de forma equivocada.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estou usando o cron, pra instalar basta usar o npm e é bem simples de usar, exemplo:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob
const job = new CronJob('*/10 * * * * *', _ => {
    console.log(new Date(1591106980002).toString())
})

job.start()
```